# Angularjs dynamic table

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have following json string to generate report in angularjs:

```
{
"result": [{name:"AUS ba",date":"02-01-2014", "result": "pass","time" : "morning","reason":"ok"}],
"result": [{name:"SA ba",date":"02-01-2014", "result": "pass","time" : "afternoon","reason":"ok"}],
"result": [{name: "NZ ba",{"date":"02-01-2014", "result": "fail","time" : "morning","reason":"ok"}],
"result": [{name:"AUS ba","date":"03-01-2014", "result": "pass","time" : "morning","reason":"ok"}],
"result": [{name:"SA ba",date":"03-01-2014", "result": "fail","time" : "morning","reason":"batch         failed"}],
"result": [{name: "NZ ba",date": "03-01-2014", "result": "fail","time" : "morning","reason":"batch error"}]
```

}

Currently I am generating table in simple format using ng-repeat:

```
Name        Date       Result  Reason    Time
AU ba      02-01-2014   PASS    Ok        Morning
AU ba      03-01-2014   ...
AU ba      04-01-2014   ...
...........
...........
```

Now I want to dynamically create table like this

```
         02-01-2014    02-01-2014    02-01-2014   02-01-2014   03-01-2014  03-01-2014
         Morning        Morning      Afternoon     Afternoon   Morning      Morning
 AU ba    Pass[Result]  ok[Reason]   Fail          Ok          Pass         ok
 SA ba    Fail          batch failed
```

Could somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a table with one row and then ng-repeat the columns in that row. In each column you can then make a table with 4 rows and one column:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3xvdGC?p=preview (I reformatted your JSON data to be able to work with it)

However, this will give problems if the text of some table cells require multiple lines. To solve that you could just use multiple ng-repeat statements:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EUKNn5?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.But I have a little problem.Now I have added one parameter added in json which repeats multiple times in json "result": [{"name":"AUS batch"date":"02-01-2014", "result": "pass","time" : "morning","reason":"ok"}],{"name":"AUS batch"date":"03-01-2014", "result": "pass","time" : "morning","reason":"ok"}] but I want to show that element only single time instead of result depends on the data passsed in "name" json string. How to do that?

Comment: This doesn't seem dynmaic to me as table row names look to be hard coded

Answer (score 0):

Write your html like this:

```
<body>
  <table ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="r in result">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{r.date}}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{r.result}}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{r.time}}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{r.reason}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

You will find a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qDHG5xgNee2WpwKoi08v?p=preview)

Note that i reformated your json, dropped some data and left all the fancy formating to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.But I have a little problem.Now I have added one parameter  in json which repeats multiple times in json "result": [{"name":"AUS batch"date":"02-01-2014", "result": "pass","time" : "morning","reason":"ok"}],{"name":"AUS batch"date":"03-01-2014", "result": "pass","time" : "morning","reason":"ok"}] but I want to show that element only single time instead of "result" tag in table depends on the data passsed in "name" json string. How to do that?

Comment: Maybe you should use these three correct Answers as a base and ask a new question, since i'm not getting what you want. Do it as before: Show us your data, Show us what you are expecting and provide links to one of the plunks or fiddles given to you. This will provide you surely with even more answers.

Comment: Do you notice that three helpfull persons spent some time and gave you correct answers, which you didn't accept. Then you changed your question to something that has to do with grouping your Json. Nonetheless all Answers are valid, but now we look kinda stoopid, like we didn't understand your question in first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use ng-repeat multiple times for each label: http://jsfiddle.net/4HHc2/2/

After reformatting your json string as an array of results, you can just call each item as follows:

```
    <td ng-repeat="d in data">{{d.date}}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.But I have a little problem.Now I have added one parameter  in json which repeats multiple times in json "result": [{"name":"AUS batch"date":"02-01-2014", "result": "pass","time" : "morning","reason":"ok"}],{"name":"AUS batch"date":"03-01-2014", "result": "pass","time" : "morning","reason":"ok"}] but I want to show that element only single time instead of "result" tag in table depends on the data passsed in "name" json string. How to do that?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to display the "name" once, so you could use `ng-model` instead of `ng-repeat` like: `<div ng-model="data">{{data[0].name}}</div>` A better way might be to restructure your JSON object.